# ElectronJS app multiple monitors on multiple X11 displays

Tags: electron, x11

I developed an ElectronJS app that, on startup, opens a `BrowserWindow` on each available monitor. It works correctly as long as all monitors are configured on same display (`display 0`).

If I configure some monitors as `display 0` and some others as `display 1`, the latter are not seen by the app and `BrowserWindow`s are created only for the former.

I searched the documentation but I haven't found anything about how multiple display configuration is managed (or if it is not supported).

Is there any option (or workaround) to allow the app to see `display 1` monitors?

Comment: Please clarify: are you talking about Linux and if yes, do you mean "display" as in X11 display? If not, where's your difference between physical monitor and software display?

Comment: Yes I am talking about X11 Linux display configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** X11 is not designed to work this way.

---

As [this answer over at Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331494) indicates, only a single display per X server is supported. Thus, you'd have to spawn multiple X servers to get multiple displays -- and explicitly specifying devices to use is known to be problematic as my X11 configuration files have disclaimers like "Having multiple `Device` sections is known to be problematic" linking to this [bug at X11's bugtracker](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32430).

Furthermore, the environment variable `DISPLAY` determines which  X display is to be used by applications. Try `echo $DISPLAY` in a shell of your choice; it will most likely output `:0`, which is display 0. At not point at runtime can an X11 application decide that it wants to communicate with another X server, because it cannot determine if another one is present (or to what display address it would be listening). It only knows (from `DISPLAY`) which one it should be talking to.

Another point to make is that you cannot have the same desktop session running across multiple X servers without going to great lengths (see the above linked answer). Also, I do not think that even this would be possible with all desktop environments, as KDE Plasma for example binds to one specific X server (to be able to handle its own set of monitor configurations).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation; if I understand correctly, an app running on DISPLAY 0 cannot be aware of the existence of other DISPLAYs. Correct?

Comment: That's what the second paragraph talks about, yes. Also, even desktop environments can't be sure.